# Do not have access to all folders except a specific folder by .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this directory structure:

```
./project/
├── docs/
├── framework/
├── .git/
├── .gitignore
├── .htaccess
└── web/
```

Address:
`http://demo.example.com/project` Or `http://project.demo.example.com`

My project front-end files are in the `web` path.
I want to block access to all files and folders except the `web` folder.
Apparently this should be done by `.htaccess`.
Initially there were solutions using `Directory` or `DirectoryMatch`, but these not allowed in `.hatccess`. So I had to use `RewriteRule`.
I also do not want it to be associated with the `project` name.

I found this command:

```
RewriteRule (docs|framework|\.git|\.gitignore|\.htaccess)(/.*)?$ - [F,NC]
```

This looks good.
Returns `403 Forbidden` for the addresses listed. It also works well for subfolders.
But the main problem is that folders may change. So I decided to change the policy and call it all folders except `web`.
To do this, I wrote this:

```
RewriteRule (?!web)(/.*)?$ - [F,NC]
```

But this does not cover all cases.
In fact it fits all patterns!

For faster testing, you can use this [link](https://regex101.com/r/UsV3ST/1) or this example [link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=422d9ab7-1bb1-41fd-94e8-d1cc54b7a376).

Comment: Maybe `^(?!(?:.*/)?web)(.*)` will do.

Comment: Note that the "MWL htaccess tester" you've linked to assumes the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, not in a subdirectory, as you are using here (which is perhaps why you've omitted the start of string anchors from your regex?).

Comment: Thanks to all the friends who commented and responded.
I solved the problem in another way. I defined such rules at a pre-project level, the `demo` directory:
```RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^(project1|project2|project3)(/.*)?$ - [F,NC]```
This allows the project to be accessed only through the subdomain, which points to the main `web` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Apache you can negate a regex (or expression) by simply prefixing it with `!` (exclamation mark).

For example, to block every URL, except those that start `/project/web/`, you can use the following in the `/project/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule !^web/ - [F]
```

Providing the `.htaccess` file is inside the `/project` subdirectory then you do not need to specify the `project/` prefix, since the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is relative to the location of the `.htaccess` file.

This needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule (?!web)(/.*)?$ - [F,NC]
> ```

Alternatively, using a negative lookahead in the regex (NB: Apache uses PCRE, not the "Java 8" flavour of regex).

You are missing the start of string anchor. But then the slash won't match since the negative-lookahead assertion does not actually match anything (and the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash).

You could use the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!web($|/)) - [F]
```

We don't need to actually match anything, the regex just needs to be "successful" in order to trigger the directive and block the request. [For example](https://regex101.com/r/UsV3ST/3)

---

Alternatively, you can use mod_authz_core instead. For example:

```
# /project/.htaccess

# Block access to everything
Require all denied
```

Create an additional access file in the `/web` sudirectory:

```
# /project/web/.htaccess

# Allow access
Require all granted
```

Or, you can do this all in `/project/.htaccess` with an Apache `<If>` expression (Apache 2.4). Although this is made a little more complex because it could be accessed by either the `project` subdomain *or* subdirectory and we are matching against the entire URL-path. For example:

```
# /project/.htaccess

# Block everything except the "/web" subdirectory
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^(/[^/]+)?/web($|/)#">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

The operator `!~` does not match the regex.